# inserting an objet with nested arrays in mongodb with moongose, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert an object like this in mongodb.

```
   {
    "client" : "Jhon"
    "items" : [
                [
                 "item": "whatever1",             
                ],
                [
                 "item": "whatever2",
                ]
     ]
   }
```

I am using Mongoose, so i have a schema like this.

```
const itemSchema= new Schema({
    item: { type: String, required: true },
})

const clientSchema = new Schema({
    client: { type: String, required: true },
    items: [itemSchema],
})
```

After i send the object to my nodejs server and create the document, i check the document created and "items" is an array that only contain _id: but nothing more.

I create the document like this.

```
createClient = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // Here i check what is receiving the server.
    clientModel.create(req.body).then(() => res.json('saved'));
}
```

In req.body, i checked that the server is receiving an object with empty arrays... is that normal? I am learning and i am new programing...

Comment: how is the request being sent from client? it seems you're not getting any data from client since you have an empty `req.body`

Comment: i am just using Postman, the funny thing is that the object has been created, i can see { "client": "Jhon",
 "Items": [ [{"_id":48327489237}],[{"_id":753894758937}]
}
So it is creating the nestead arrays but is not inserting... as i said... is rare.. i check with console.log(req.body) and nothing is inside the arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your payload does not seem to be correct.

```
[ "item": "whatever1" ]
```

is not valid JSON and won't be parsed properly. Try changing your payload to:

```
{
  "client": "Jhon"
  "items": [
    { "item": "whatever1" },
    { "item": "whatever2" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Perfect! is working, it seems that was not parsed properly, thank you!